# Как сменить цвет гамбургера на белый, если ему задано свойство mix-blend-mode: difference?

Tags: html, css

Как задать цвет гамбургеру, чтобы он на первой странице был белым? Он у меня отображается бирюзовым цветом. Я его делал c помощью hamburgers.css и блоку hamburger_wrapper я задал свойство mix-blend-mode: difference, далее я задал белый цвет для самих составляющих гамбургера, но выдал он мне не то, что надо.

```css
.hamburger_wrapper {
  display: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner:after,
.hamburger-inner:before {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger_wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger hamburger--spin">
   <div class="hamburger-box">
  <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
  </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Сам сайт c96180og.beget.tech
код jsfiddle.net/1hg407ca/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что мешает на заданной странице ему еще один класс добавить, который через `!important` пропишет нужные свойства?

Comment: то есть при нахождении гамбургера на главной странице, задать класс, который будет окрашивать его в белый? Как это сделать?

Comment: а что вы менять можете? код css, html&